# Can an Apache web site call asp.net functions in an assembly?

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, .net-core

I have a window box hosting an Apache web server, which runs PHP web application.  Now I have asp.net class library dll (an assemble) from another project and want to call some functions of the dll from the PHP application.  Would you please advise me how many options I can have?

Following are what I thought of but not sure if they are feasible:

1. Host an IIS web server side by side the Apache server in the same box and the IIS server runs a web service that wraps up the dll.  (will there be conflict between the 2 servers, say port number etc.?)
2. Convert the .net dll (ver 4.5) into Asp.net Core library and set up
   a web a service) directly side by side the PHP site under the Apache server (how will I do it, is there a guide for me to follow?)
3. Since the Apache is hosted in a Window box, there could be a way that the dll can be directly accessed by PHP code or accessed through a wrapper (there is a bin folder or some area where the dll can be put in and get called)

If there are multiple ways to do it, which way sounds easier?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try to use the Foreign Function Interface (FFI) in PHP 7.4.  The next easiest method would be to wrap the DLL in a CGI program and forward the requests from Apache.

Comment: @Alex Barker.  Does the .net assembly fit the FFI? Do you have an example? from here "https://jolicode.com/blog/php-7-4-ffi-what-you-need-to-know" it say "All languages able to compile to a shared library (.so) are not systematically good to be bind to PHP. It’s better to use languages without runtime (C / C++ / Rust / …) because a runtime may have side effects"

Comment: There _could be_ issues depending on what is going on inside of the DLL. Check out the DLL using [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see if all the symbols are resolved.  I do not have any examples for FFI, but there are how to guides out there. All shared library code should be roughly the same regardless of language; .net does work fine with other FFI interfaces, so unless you are doing something wired, I would expect it would probably work fine.